# merge two tables when one table has key, but the other has only a range of the key

Tags: python, merge

```
df1:
 lower_bound_ip_address           upper_bound_ip_address    country
0              16777216.0                16777471          Australia
1              16777472.0                16777727          China
2              16777728.0                16778239          China
3              16778240.0                16779263          Australia
4              16779264.0                16781311          China

df: 
     ip_address
0    7.327584e+08
1    3.503114e+08
2    2.621474e+09
3    3.840542e+09
4    4.155831e+08
5    2.809315e+09
6    3.987484e+09
7    1.692459e+09
8    3.719094e+09
9    3.416747e+08
```

I want to match df['ip_address'] with df1['country']. Certain ip_address range is corresponding to specific country, for example:  729808896-734003199 indicates Japan. How to do that?

I tried the following three codes, all failed:

```
for x in df['ip_address']:
    if x<=df1['upper_bound_ip_address'] and x>=df1['lower_bound_ip_address']:
        df['country']=df1['country']

TypeError: len() of unsized object


for x in df['ip_address']:
   for y in df1:
    if x<=y['upper_bound_ip_address'] and x>=y['lower_bound_ip_address']:
        x['country']=y['country']

TypeError: string indices must be integers



for x in range(0, len(df)):
  for y in range(0, len(df1)):
    if (df.iloc[x,'ip_address'] <= df1.iloc[y,'upper_bound_ip_address'] and (df.iloc[x,'ip_address'] >= df1.iloc[y,'lower_bound_ip_address']):
        df['country']=df1.iloc[y,'country']

 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve can be done using this snippet. Since you want to compare with two columns: upper_bound and lower_bound and both have the same index, it would be logical to iterate row by row rather than entire column at once.

```
for i, x in df.iterrows():
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        if x['ip_address']<=row['upper_bound_ip_address'] and x['ip_address']>=row['lower_bound_ip_address']:
            df.ix[i, 'country']=row['country']
```